# How to call JSON webservice from background in iPhone

Tags: iphone

i need to know is it possible to call json webservices from background, when the user press the home button, i am calling this method from background execution

```
- (void) runTimer 
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateAllVisibleElements)toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 
}

- (void) updateAllVisibleElements  {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    if(service == nil)
    {
        service = [[WebService alloc] init];
    }
    [service getlocationID:currentLatitude andlongitude:currentLongitute];
    [pool release];
}
```

and in called the function [service getlocation id] however after that it doesn't show any response or data recieves and app terminates, plz help me

Comment: IIRC - no network communications are allowed during background processing (except waiting for PUSH events)

Comment: thanks for the response so according to that its not possible to get any kind of response from webserver when app is in the background

Comment: see Daniel's answer below, it may be a workaround to achieve what you desire though I would guess since you mentioned webservice(s) that your task will not be short.

Comment: i have tried what dainel have given however my webservices will be called in certain time interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(service == nil)
{
    service = [[WebService alloc] init];
}
[service getlocationID:currentLatitude andlongitude:currentLongitute];
```

Note that you never test that `service` is a good value (not nil) before you make the call

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to happen immediately after the app goes to the background, you can probably use [`-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  That should work as long as the task doesn't take too long.

Comment: This approach DOES indeed work - I use it to manage some asynchronous web service activity that happens in just this scenario.

Comment: @Roger would you please provide me the example for that i tried it previously

Comment: There's a pretty decent example right in Apple's documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW12